# The URLs in the content of the page are broken when I use Nginx to proxy pass a subdirectory to a server

Tags: docker, nginx, phpmyadmin, webserver, reverse-proxy

I am using `proxy_pass` in Nginx to redirect `/phpmyadmin[/]` to a container where PHPMyAdmin is running (the project is available [here](https://github.com/sajjadhesami/sampleDockerNginxLoadBalancer) on Github). The problem is that when I use *https://localhost/phpmyadmin/*, I get the HTML and content of PHPMyAdmin in the correct way, but, when I drop "/" at the end of the  URL, it returns me the HTML with the wrong resource URLs (such as *https://localhost/favicon.ico* instead of *https://localhost/**phpmyadmin**/favicon.ico*). My Nginx config file looks like this:

```
upstream backend {
    server app1:9000;
    server app2:9000;
    server app3:9000;
    server app4:9000;
}
upstream docker_phpmyadmin {
    server phpmyadmin:443;
}
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www;

    location ~ /phpmyadmin {
        # (START) some queries don't work when modsecurity is on
        modsecurity off;
        # (END) some queries don't work when modsecurity is on


        # (START) large databases might demand long time and large memory
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        client_body_buffer_size 10M;
        proxy_read_timeout 6000;
        proxy_send_timeout 6000;
        # (END) large databases might demand long time and large memory

        rewrite /phpmyadmin/?(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://docker_phpmyadmin;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    modsecurity on;
    modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    error_page 404 error.html;
    location = /error.html {
        root /var/www;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 10d;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass backend;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

The same issue arises when I try to use MailCow in my project using:

```
location ~ /mailcow {

        rewrite /mailcow/?(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://docker_nginx_mailcow;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Comment: Then maybe you should not drop the trailing slash? Use `location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ { ... }` instead of `location ~ /phpmyadmin { ... }`, and nginx will automatically redirect `/phpmyadmin` to `/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you. I had tried it with `~`, but `^~` actually did the trick.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Your suggestion helped me to fix the problem with PHPMyAdmin. But with mailcow, I get broken URLs both with `https://localhost/mailcow` and `https://localhost/mailcow/`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I used a method similar to your answer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62967394/nginx-proxy-resource-loading-issue).